# Form Problem in ONLY IE6 and IE7

Tags: html, css

For some reason the form inputs are pushing off the left margin.. I have no clue why!

Below is the link..

http://mimedx.com/mg/contactus.php

I have no clue why this is happening.  Probably Microsoft being Microsoft and having some random rule that conflicts with standards..

CSS:

```
#content form { overflow: hidden; width: 550px; }
#content form ul { padding: 0; }
#content form li { list-style: none; float: left;  width: 250px; padding: 4px 0; }
#content form label { display: block;  width: 100px; line-height: 15px; font-size: 1em; padding-bottom: 2px; font-weight: bold;}
#content form input { display: block;  width: 200px; padding: 4px; margin: 0; line-height: 14px; font-size: .9em; background-color: #f7f7f7; border: 1px solid #d4d4d4; color: #4d4d4d; }
```

HTML:

```
        <form action="/mail.php" method="post" name="contactForm" id="contactForm">           
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="phone">Phone</label>
            <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
        </li>           
        <li class="full">
            <label for="comments">Comments</label>
            <textarea name="comments" id="comments"></textarea>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
        </li>
    </ul>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list elements are responsible, quite a common problem in IE.

Try setting

```
#content form ul { margin: 0; }
#content form li { margin: 0; }
```

More generally, you might find using a [reset css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) useful. This removes browser specific styling and gives you a 'blank canvas' to work from. I always use the [YUI Reset](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/) but there are plenty of options out there.

Comment: duh. for some reason i thought i had already run a reset.. woops!! thank ya :)